# Update displayed vuex store without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, store

I'm attempting to have variables displayed from my backend which automatically update. For transfering these variables I'm using vuex store and nuxt.config.js. And for changing the variables in the backend I'm using API calls. Currently, the data only updates when the page is refreshed. I display the variables by setting `{{ this.$store.getters.getUserInfo.variable }}` on the page of my frontend.

I've tried creating a mapstate computed function, and I tried setting the variable in the `data()` function. However, none have worked.

Backend API function

```
exports.getUser = (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        user: {
            username: loadedUser.username,
...
```

Frontend vuex store

```
export const getters = {
  getUserInfo(state) {
    console.log("State", state)
    return state.auth.user;
  }
};
```

Transfering the data with nuxt.config.js

```
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        user: {
          property: "user",
          autoFetch: true
        },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read about the "Mutation".
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html
When you create a mutation, you can commit the new value to change the state

Answer (score 0):

this might help to understand the concept of vuex and it's usage [uni-directional data flow](https://medium.com/@softwarecf/uni-directional-data-flow-with-vuex-4f31d7ac8c83)

Comment: Welcome to SO. While the link you provided may be helpful, link-only answers are discouraged [for various reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/1227775). Please [edit] to include the relevant information directly in your answer and add some context and explanation. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).